# HandlerInterceptor: The Interceptor is not being called

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am implementing a `MyInterceptor.java` class which extends `HandlerInterceptor` implementing `preHandle()`,`postHandle()` and`afterCompletion()`. The interceptor methods are not being called.

Here is MyInterceptor.java

```
    package com.mykong.common.interceptor;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

public class MyInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Pre-handle");

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Post-handle");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("After completion handle");
    }

}
```

Here is mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" />

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <bean class="com.mykong.common.interceptor.MyInterceptor" />
            <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>

   <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Here is web.xml

```
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>

        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

I am running this project on eclipse. I am  not able to see "Pre-handle","Post-handle" and "After completion handle" being printed in the Console tab of eclipse.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Did you tried this after invoking a service ? This gets triggered only when you invoke a service

Comment: Yes, I invoked a service. It returns the response without any problem. However, "Pre-handle","Post-handle" and "After completion handle" are not being printed in the console

Answer (score 0):

Change your `mvc-dispatcher` servlet mapping in your `web.xml` as follows:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Also, edit your `mvc:interceptors` in `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` file as below:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
            <mvc:interceptor>
                <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
                <bean class="com.mykong.common.interceptor.MyInterceptor" />           
            </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Optionally, you can remove below entry from `web.xml`, as by default Spring looks for `servletName-servlet.xml` inside your **`WEB-INF`** folder:

```
 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

 <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
 </listener>
```

Comment: Thanks Arpit. I made the edits you suggested, but it is still not calling the interceptor.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: There is no exception. My service is called and the response comes back. But before the handler corresponding to a request is called, it should call preHandle(), which is not being called.

Comment: When I make a request curl http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/operation/hi ,  the handler for this request is called and the response is got back successfully. But the methods of MyInterceptor.java are not called.

Comment: When I start the tomcat from eclipse and make the curl request, the interceptor is not called. However, when I started tomcat from terminal and made the curl request, the interceptor works, printing prehandle, posthandle messages in catalina.out.  Any idea why it doesnt work when tomcat is started from eclipse? Thanks!

Comment: this is related to logging and logging configuration of your app, not with the  spring interceptors

Comment: The problem is resolved! There was a problem in the BuildPath. I just did mvn clean install, started tomcat again and sent the request. It calls the interceptor.  Thanks! :)

Comment: It's because, your tomcat is picking up the `.war` file with the old code. Also, if answers works for you then accept it.